# What are the languages, I can use to create UNIX utilities?

Tags: scripting, unix

I need to write a unix utility, what are the languages, I can use? I am good with C/C++, but I dont know any scripting language like shell/bash/perl/python. But used linux for most of my projects and predominantly use command line. Please advise....

Comment: And what would be the problem? Because the answer would *really* depend on *that* ;)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Given your username I guess you're better with windows ones (:D) But good call :-)

Comment: Pretty much any scripting language. What type of utility is this?

Comment: Basic one..... LVM size and stuff...

Comment: If you are familiar with C, why don't you use that?  (Apart from the obvious, which isn't obvious if you are not familiar with a scripting language. :^)

Comment: Thats sounds like a good idea..... Do you know, how to parse a file in C/C++..... I need to parse a file, so thought scripting will be easy and natural way to go...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use any language that is available for your Unix system.